# Как начать цикл показа картинки сначала

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт который реализует смену картинки при клике на нее. Все бы хорошо, но задача в том, что надо чтобы когда прокликал определенное количество изображений, то показ картинок начинался с самого начала. Подскажите как реализовать...

```js
<script language="javascript">
        var i=0;
        var image=document.getElementById("image");
        var imgs=new Array('img/img1.jpg','img/img2.jpg','img/img3.jpg'); // картинки через запятую
        function imgsrc(){
            i++;
        image.src=imgs[i]; 
        } 
        
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-circle" id="image" src="img/img1.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();" >
                    
                    
                    <p>Гробы <b>от 1800</b></p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function imgsrc(){
    i++;
    image.src=imgs[ i % imgs.length ]; 
}
```

Думаю этот вариант вам подойдет.